# Change shared drive settings by Drive.Drives.update

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

We use Google Drive and are working on a tool to automatically create shared drives.

However, Drive.Drives.update is not working properly. I would like to apply shared drive settings, but nothing happens when I run the program. Could you please tell me what I need to improve?

I tried running the following program. Unfortunately, the shared drive settings remained the same as before. No errors occurred when running the program.

```
  var updateOptions = {
    "name": "XXXXXX",
    "restrictions": {
      "adminManagedRestrictions": true,
      "domainUsersOnly": true,
      "driveMembersOnly": true,
      "sharingFoldersRequiresOrganizerPermission" : true,
      "copyRequiresWriterPermission" : true
    }
  };

  var updateResources = {
    "useDomainAdminAccess": true
  };
 
  var updateDrive = Drive.Drives.update(updateResources, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", updateOptions);
```

Comment: Is it possible that the shared drive settings in Google Workspace Admin console are somehow affecting this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to update the settings for a shared drive in Google Drive using Google Apps Script.
        However, your code appears to be missing some necessary components and might not be properly structured. To
        update shared drive settings using Google Apps Script, you should follow this general approach:

1. Retrieve the existing settings for the shared drive.
2. Modify the settings as needed.
3. Update the shared drive with the new settings.

Here's a modified example of how you can achieve this:

```
function updateSharedDriveSettings() {
                // ID of the shared drive you want to update
                var sharedDriveId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                        
                // Retrieve the existing shared drive settings
                var sharedDrive = Drive.Drives.get(sharedDriveId);
                        
                // Modify the settings as needed
                sharedDrive.name = "New Name";
                sharedDrive.restrictions = {
                        adminManagedRestrictions: true,
                        domainUsersOnly: true,
                        driveMembersOnly: true,
                        sharingFoldersRequiresOrganizerPermission: true,
                        copyRequiresWriterPermission: true
                 };
                      
                // Update the shared drive with the new settings
                Drive.Drives.update(sharedDrive, sharedDriveId);
              }
```

Make sure to replace ``"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"` ` with the actual ID of the shared drive you want to update.

In this modified code:

1. We first retrieve the existing shared drive settings using ` `Drive.Drives.get(sharedDriveId)` `.
2. Then, we modify the settings as needed, including the drive's name and the restrictions.
3. Finally, we update the shared drive using
               ` `Drive.Drives.update(sharedDrive, sharedDriveId)` `.

Please ensure that you have the necessary permissions to update shared drives in your Google Drive organization, as administrative access might be required for some settings. Additionally, make sure you are using a valid shared drive ID.

Comment: Mr. Bheem, thank you for your prompt reply.

I followed your advice and rewrote the code using the valid Drive ID.

Comment: The execution results are as follows:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.drives.update failed with error: The requesting user does not have the administrator privilege required to manage the shared drive XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

Comment: Instead I changed the last line to the following and ran it again:

      const updateResources = {
        "useDomainAdminAccess": true
      }; 
      
      Drive.Drives.update(updateResources, sharedDrive.id, sharedDrive);

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happened as a result. I have domain administrator authority, but the shared drive settings will remain unchanged.